# Email Subscriptions with Verification

Tags: 7, notifications

I feel like I'm missing something, because I can't find a module that does this, but it seems like it should be really common.

I would like users to be able to simply enter their email address to subscribe to my site so that I can send them an email whenever I post a new Article. I don't want to require them to create a full drupal account, just a simple email address and then click a verify link.

I've tried Simple Subscription and it provided a simple form block which provides essentially what I'm looking for on the front end:

[image]

However, when a user enters their email address this module doesn't provide a verification email. So, I need something more complicated that Simple Subscription.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simple subscription](http://drupal.org/project/simple_subscription/) validates email address. It did work for me. I used the latest version of the module.
It also provides a hook `hook_simple_subscription` which allows modules to do something with the simple subscription form results such as sending email for subscription verification.

Comment: Does it send subscription verifications and such?

Comment: not sure what you mean "subscription verifications".

Comment: When you enter your email address into the site, the system will send you an email with a verification link that you can click to confirm your subscription.

Comment: I think you need to write a hook for this. Check the file **simple_subscription.api.php** in the module folder. I updated my answer.

Comment: Then it's not doing what I'd like. If I'm going to write my own module code to handle this, then I'll just write the whole module exactly the way I'd like it to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use my module for this [Total Subscription](https://drupal.org/project/total_subscription).

> Total Subscription provides functionality which would allow the user to subscribe to node pages, taxonomy terms, etc. The main feature which distinguishes it from other subscription modules is that it allows subscription for Anonymous along with Authenticated users.